# video overlay doesnt work in unity tango api

Tags: video, overlay, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

The video overlay option is not working in the Project Tango API. I have tried building the sample Augmented reality Scenes and instead of the video overlay I only get a white background. I have not enabled the multi threaded rendering in the player settings in Unity. Still the issue exists.

I am using Motorola G2 for testing the built application. I tried with different devices but still the same result. I tried sample apps following the tutorial for Area learning and still the same result.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Tango SDK is only for devices with new sensor technology which allow for depth sensing, motion tracking and area reconstruction.

Currently, only Google's own development kit, a tablet, supports the Tango SDK. The first phone to support it is a Lenovo device, but is not released yet.

The issue you complain about is most likely that the devices you test on does not have this new sensor technology.

I suggest you read up by searching on google tango and go to the project homepage

Comment: Yes, now I get it. I too had this doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the applications that use Tango API require the shared library called as Tango Core. This can be downloaded from Google Play. But this app is supported only in the Tango device.

Only with this app as a shared library the app is able to launch. Else you get a missing shared library exception.